# How to fix "attribute android:layout_width, layout_height and textview not allowed here" after installing Android Studio

Tags: android

I installed android studio and after creating a project there is some error with my `Main_Activity.xml.`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

all of these attributes are not allowed here; And also similar errors in `AndroidManifest.`

Comment: Could you add full code of activity_main.xml?

Comment: @M.Qasim  - please share full screenshot or xml code here.

Comment: can you try clean and rebuild

Answer (score 4):

For me, this fixes the problem:

> Files->Sync Project with Gradle Files

(Note that I was using a VPN due to the Sanctions of the USA)

Comment: We are all victims of politics which really it's not our business.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the app I downloaded from Github was built using Android SDK platform 23, which I hadn't downloaded with my Android Studio install.

Open the build.gradle file (Module:app), that is in the Gradle Scripts dropdown from the Android view (in Android Studio).

Inside this file, you'll see something like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

This means I had to go to the menu bar at the top, and go into Tools, to the SDK manager. From there I had to show package details, and find the sdk with version 23 and download it. After that, your app should work.

Answer (score -1):

I just faced this kind of issue and fixing this is really simple, you just need to click on menubar File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart and then restart the Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Mine was: "**Attribute android:gravity is not allowed here**"

I fixed that by closing android studio. When I restarted it, the error was gone.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30271185)

Comment: That's not the error in the question, though.